# Dart/WebStorm Issue

Tags: dart, webstorm, dart2js

Forgive me for being a novice. I am a self taught coder which I know is tough because I didn't learn the fundamentals first etc...

With that said, I am 6 months into a web app and had to move to a new machine. On the new machine I am having a weird issue that I do not know how to figure out.

My code on the old machine worked in Dartium for debugging and when built and deployed with firebase hosting.

My code on the new machine works in Dartium, but has console errors in Chrome debugger, and when built and deployed.

In WebStorm, when I look at my breakpoints with Dartium, they are all checked as valid, but when I look with Chrome, about 5% are not checked as valid and typically error out there.

I believe the issues are centered around DSON objects/conversions.

I know that this is not enough information to diagnose the problem, but I am looking for guidance on where to start? I am not looking for anyone to do it for me, just point me in the direction that I need to study and I will figure it out!

Thank you in advance!

```
ReferenceError: activeBorrowerObject is not defined
at eval (eval at sendNewBorrowerToStream$1 (http://localhost:53854/main.dart.js:87688:9), <anonymous>:1:1)
at CoreService.sendNewBorrowerToStream$1 (http://localhost:53854/main.dart.js:87688:9)
at http://localhost:53854/main.dart.js:88492:23
at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (http://localhost:53854/main.dart.js:7344:15)
at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.dart._wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (http://localhost:53854/main.dart.js:7839:14)
at _awaitOnObject_closure.dart._awaitOnObject_closure.call$1 (http://localhost:53854/main.dart.js:7827:34)
at StaticClosure.dart._rootRunUnary (http://localhost:53854/main.dart.js:7683:18)
at _ZoneDelegate.runUnary$3 (http://localhost:53854/main.dart.js:10950:41)
at NgZone.dart.NgZone._runUnary$5 (http://localhost:53854/main.dart.js:30281:24)
at Object.eval (eval at Closure_forwardCallTo (http://localhost:53854/main.dart.js:4917:14), <anonymous>:2:47)
```

Comment: it says activeBorrowerObject isnt defined. so is it? if you can actually find it and you see it is defined then is it referenced in the file? just go through all possibilities for why it errors

Comment: I think I've done that. Here is what is happening: Just assume 2 form fields are submitted and the activeBorrowerObject is created, and saved in firebase. The object is also stored in a "coreService" and that works. Next, step 2 is, the program navigates to a new component, and that component retrieves the activeBorrowerObject from the coreService. That is where I get the error. I have tried data binding, getting it from the service in the initializer, getting it from the service in the ngOnInit....no luck